# passing get variables without opening URL

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read a web page in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259892/how-to-read-a-web-page-in-php)

I'm sure there is some simple way to do this. I need to pass get variables through to my cart software to record a conversion, but not redirect the user, I just want the server to send GET variables to a URL. I'd rather not turn on allow_url_fopen in php.ini.

Anyone know the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request.

Comment: Or use [**cURL** or one of the other PHP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259892/how-to-read-a-web-page-in-php/2259893#2259893) to do a server-side request.

Answer (score 0):

Server side, your best option is probably to use [cURL](http://php.net/curl)  - see the documentation for details, it's not too difficult to use.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/script.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if ($response === false) {
    // Failed to connect or some error occurred
} else {
    // Everything was fine, check the response here if you need to
}
```